# Angular radio button

Tags: angular, radio-button

I have a set of three radio buttons which are three form controls of a form group in Angular 4. I want only one of them to be selected at a time for which I have to give three of them a common name but while doing so I get an error saying:

> Error:
> If you define both a name and a formControlName attribute on your radio button, their values
> must match.

```
<html>
    <form [formGroup]="myGroup">
    <input type="radio" formControlName="food" name="food">
    <input type="radio" formControlName="food" name="food">
    <input type="radio" formControlName="food" name="food">
    </form>
</html>
```

I cannot give same `formControlName` to all three as they should be unique. What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it is a Question and Answer site where you can ask a **specific** programming question that **can be answered** rather than discussed. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and then edit your question to conform with the site guidelines. Off-topic questions such as this one are routinely closed, but if edited to ask an *answerable* question, can be re-opened again. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set a unique value to each of them

```
<html>
    <form [formGroup]="myGroup">
    <input type="radio" formControlName="food" name="food" value="banana" checked>
    <input type="radio" formControlName="food" name="food" value="strawberry">
    <input type="radio" formControlName="food" name="food" value ="nut">
    </form>
</html>
```

This should do.